# Show accepted children but not parents from filterAcceptsRow() in QSortFilterProxyModel in QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

**Background:**

I have a QTreeView that is pretending to be a QTableView by expandAll() and setIndentation(0). I now want to filter using a QSortFilterProxyModel, but the standard filterAcceptsRow() only accepts the row if all parents are accepted as well. I've worked around this by implementing filterAcceptsItself() and filterHasAcceptedChildren() based on a previous C++ example.

**Problem:**

Currently both the rows that are accepted themselves (i.e. those containg the string sstr that I'm searching for) as well as their parents are shown in the QTreeView. However, I want to hide the parents. My current workaround using a hiddenRows list unfortunately hides all rows and I can't figure out why the rows that are themselves accepted are being added to the list. Also, perhaps someone has an idea of how to make this more efficient?

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSourceModel(parent)
        self.rootItem = self.sourceModel().root()
        self.sstr = None
        self.hiddenRows = []
        self.prevRows = []

    def search(self, sstr):
        self.sstr = sstr
        self.prevRows = self.hiddenRows
        self.hiddenRows = []
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        if self.filterAcceptsRowItself(source_row, source_parent):
            return True

        if self.hasAcceptedChildren(source_row, source_parent):
            return True

        return False

    def hasAcceptedChildren(self, source_row, source_parent):
        item = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        if not item.isValid():
            raise Exception(f"Item invalid: parent {source_parent}, row {source_row}")
            return False

        childCount = self.sourceModel().rowCount(item)
        if childCount == 0:
            return False
        for i in range(0, childCount):
            if self.filterAcceptsRow(i, item):
                return True

        return False

    def filterAcceptsRowItself(self, source_row, source_parent):
        if self.sstr:
            num_columns = self.sourceModel().columnCount(source_parent)
            for i in range(num_columns):
                item_text = (
                    self.sourceModel().index(source_row, i, source_parent).data()
                )

                if self.filterCaseSensitivity() == Qt.CaseInsensitive:
                    if self.sstr.lower() in item_text.lower():
                        return True
                else:
                    if self.sstr in item_text:
                        return True
            if self.hasAcceptedChildren(source_row, source_parent):
                self.hiddenRows.append(self.index(source_row, 0, source_parent))
            return False
        return False

class MyTableView(qtw.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, model, shown_columns=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.filter_model = MySortFilterProxyModel(self.model)
        self.filter_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.expandAll()
        self.setIndentation(0)
        if shown_columns:
            self.setShownColumns(shown_columns)

    def setShownColumns(self, shown_columns):
        for i in range(self.model.columnCount(QModelIndex())):
            if self.model.headerData(i, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole) in shown_columns:
                self.setColumnHidden(i, False)
            else:
                self.setColumnHidden(i, True)

    def search(self, sstr):
        if sstr:
            for index in self.filter_model.prevRows:
                if index.isValid():
                    self.setRowHidden(index.row(), index.parent(), False)
            self.setModel(self.filter_model)
            self.filter_model.search(sstr)

            for index in self.filter_model.hiddenRows:
                if index.isValid():
                    # PROBLEM HERE
                    self.setRowHidden(index.row(), index.parent(), True)
        else:
            self.setModel(self.model)

        self.expandAll()
```

Comment: You can't filter out the parents, obviously, as removing them removes their children (imagine having a window with a button: you can't show the button if you hide the window). You have to find a way to make them unaccessible/invisible. You could try to return 0-height sizeHints, or force individual vertical headers heights. Otherwise, you need to map the model to a virtial representation that only shows children.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I'm doing. The filter accepts both those rows that fulfill my criteria (in filterAcceptsRowItself) and those that have accepted Children (in hasAcceptedChildren). That works without a problem. The thing I can't figure out is how to hide only the parents. Currently I'm trying to use QTreeWidget's setRowHidden() method but I'm hiding both parents and children.

Comment: Mmmh. I'm not sure I'm understanding the logic behind your code. Can you provide a minimal implementation to show how it should behave?